# JQuery .prop( propertyName, value ) changes value when it's Filelist in FireFox

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I'm doing some file upload work with file input element.

The functionality works fine in Chrome, but strangely it doesn't in Firefox.

It narrows down to the 'value' parameter I pass into the .prop() function gets changed unexpectedly.

How come the value to be assigned to the property gets changed in FF?

jQuery v2.1.1

The code is like:

```
$(this).prop("files", files);

Pic 1. RHS value before the change
Pic 2. LHS value before the change
Pic 3. RHS value after the change
```

[image: RHS value before the change]

[image: LHS value before the change]

[image: RHS value after the change]

Comment: works with .attr() though.

Comment: Shouldn't be able to set files or value of a file input using js (other than empty string) for security reasons

Comment: Oh, it makes sense if it's a security reasons. But why the 'value' parameter has been changed and why .attr() maintain its value?

Comment: Changing attribute has no relevance. It's the property that matters (and gets submitted). value attribute is only used by browser to set initial property on page load...except for file input

Comment: Create a text input with a value attribute. Then type something else. The value attribute doesn't change ... only the value property does